Issues Running Macro with Cap IQ Plugin via PowerShell Script
I need assistance with automating an Excel process that involves running a macro which utilizes functions from the Cap IQ plugin. Here’s the scenario:
Objective:
Generate an email from an Excel spreadsheet containing dynamic data every day at 12 PM. The macro performs calculations using functions from the Cap IQ plugin.
Current Setup:
I have written a PowerShell script that opens, activates, and runs the macro in the Excel spreadsheet.
The Cap IQ plugin is installed and functions correctly when the macro is run manually in Excel.
The PowerShell script verifies that the plugin is installed and connected
Issue:
When I run the macro manually from Excel, it executes correctly without any issues. However, when I run the macro via the PowerShell script, Excel does not recognize the functions from the Cap IQ plugin and displays #NAME errors.
I am seeking guidance on how to ensure the Cap IQ plugin functions are recognized when run via PowerShell.
$excelFilePath = "\path"
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$excel.Visible = $true
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($excelFilePath)

when I see the excel spreadsheet.
I see #NAME.
When I open regularly it works.
Are there any additional steps or configurations needed to properly load and utilize the Cap IQ plugin in this automated scenario?
Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated.
#NAME errors where Excel doesnt recognize the plugin

You need to load the plug-in programmatically.

When I print the addIn Properties it seems it's already connected/Installed on.
Name: SNLXLAddin.xla
Installed: True
Title: MI Office Excel Compatibility Add-in
Description: S&P Cap IQ Pro Excel Add-In
Connect: True

New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application doesn't load any add-ins. You have to do so explicitly.

How do I explicitly add an excel plugin?

For an .xla add-in, you need to actually open that file. For a COM add-in, I believe you need to call the Connect method.

possibly helpful as an alternative to opening the .xla.
